# VBA lookup outputs incompatible types

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a inversed vlookup, from bottom to top, using lookup, it works fine in the excel tab but I'm having a few issues translating it to VBA.

Excel formula: `=LOOKUP(2;1/(Table1[Code]=L4);Table1[Key])`

VB:

```
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Base")
Set sht3 = Worksheets("Extra")

rng1 = sht2.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
rng2 = sht2.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value
cll = sht3.Cells(2, 12)

rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (rng1 = cll), rng2)
sht3.Cells(2,13) = rw
```

Any tips?

Comment: You can't compare or divide arrays like that in VBA. Use `Evaluate` instead, passing the same formula string you would use in a cell.

Comment: Or use Find searching up to find the last cell that has that value and use offset to return the correct value.

Comment: Evaluate doesn't work for me, I need the result of the row in VBA.

Comment: I tried using Find, but couldn't get it quite right

Comment: `Evaluate` will return exactly the same result as the formula you mention, so it's hard to see how it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I mean it because evaluate puts de formula value in the spreadsheet, I need the value to be saved in VBA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Find` instead of a lookup you can do it like this:

```
Sub Find_from_bottom()

Dim Rowaddress As Long
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

Set sht2 = Worksheets("Base")
Set sht3 = Worksheets("Extra")

Rowaddress = Range("A:A").Find(sht3.Cells(2, 12).Value, Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
sht3.Cells(2, 13) = sht2.Cells(Rowaddress, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Tryied your sugestion but it returns an error, shouldnt `Range...` in `Rowadress` be linked to a sheet? Something like `sht3.Range...`

Comment: Yes exactly at best you should put the sheet before as you wrote `sht3.Range`, if you don't write it, then `Range.` refers to the active sheet (which might bring an error). If the Value is not in The Range("A:A") you also might get an error